# Javascript error message 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ('

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am receiving an error in my Javascript. Can someone please help me remedy this?

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Here's my full code:

```
function($) {
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(':input').blur(function () {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Modals', 'completed', $(this).attr('name')]);
        } 
        else {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Modals', 'skipped', $(this).attr('name')]);
    });
});
})(jQuery);

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '** ANALYTICS ID HERE **']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '**DOMAIN HERE**']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], ['_trackPageLoadTime']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing brace to close this `else` block...

```
  else {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Modals', 'skipped', $(this).attr('name')]);
});
```

This is how it should be...

```
  else {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Modals', 'skipped', $(this).attr('name')]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're not opening this parenthesis

```
})(jQuery);
```